# Recovering a graph that consists entirely of disjoint cliques given edge probabilities

Tags: graph-theory, clustering

We have $n$ nodes and an $n \times n$ probabilistic adjacency matrix $A$ such that $A_{ij}$ is the probability that an edge exists between nodes $i$ and $j$.

Our objective is to find the maximum probability graph of the nodes consisting entirely of **disjoint cliques**.

I assume that this is very hard to do optimally, however I'm curious about the kinds of approaches that are used to find good solutions to such problems. It seems deeply related, perhaps equivalent, to clustering.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you saying that the $A_{ij}$ are given, and we want to find, among all possible realizations which are a disjoint union of cliques, the one with the highest probability of occurring?

Comment: Yes exactly. Apologies for not being clear.